# CakePHP variable set in AppController is visible in one controller and not visible in another

Tags: variables, cakephp, global-variables, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

In cakephp 2.0 I'm trying to set a variable in AppController so this is accessible at any subclasses and views in the following way:

```
function beforeFilter() {       
    $this->set('lang', self::getCurrentLanguage()); // set to access it also from Views
    $this->set('conf', self::getConfig());          // set to access it also from Views     
    $this->lang = self::getCurrentLanguage();   // set to access it also from Controllers
    $this->conf = self::getConfig();            // set to access it also from Controllers
    $this->set('user', $this->Session->read('User'));
    $this->user = $this->Session->read('User');     
}
```

Everything runs smoothly when I use echo $lang; in View and echo $this->lang in any controllers except one with its respective View:

```
echo $conf;
echo $lang;
---
Notice (8): Undefined variable: conf [APP\views\admin\products.ctp, line 7]
Notice (8): Undefined variable: lang [APP\views\admin\products.ctp, line 8]
```

Since class AdminController extends AppController, I am expecting same behaviour as any other subclass of AppController has. Already spent half-day on finding where the problem may be. Where is a starting point of investigation? What should I check first?

What is wrong with AdminController as it doesn't "see" that variables, but other classes don't have this problem?
This is the only workaround that works for this particular class:

```
$this->set('conf', parent::getConfig());
```

Comment: Update: I tried to put exit() in AppController. Seems that AdminController doesn't react to any changes in AppController, so it doesn't see not only any variables set in it but the entire controller is not visible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have defined `AdminController::beforeFilter()` and have forgotten to call `AppController::beforeFilter()`.

In `AdminController`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

The [App Controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller) section in the Cookbook warns you about this:

> Also remember to call AppController‘s callbacks within child controller callbacks for best results:

Comment: Perfecty noted! None of the other controllers except AdminController were defined beforeFilter! So adding parent::beforeFilter(); of course solved variable visibility in AdminController and saved my day ;) Thank you!

Comment: @djtester We've all been there at least once :)